# Issue with Parsing through JSON data for error message

Tags: android, json

I have asked a question similar to this a couple a days ago but now I have ran into a problem.  In my `asynctask` below I am parsing through web service data.  When my the web service returns this data to my `json` string

```
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891): {
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891): "all" :    {
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):    "count" : 25,
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):    "questions" : [     {   
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Id" : "20100728112033AAb4hTA",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Subject" : "What is the oldest a bitch can more or less safely breed?",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Content" : "Don't worry I'm not going to breed - both my bitches are getting neutered in the next year, as is my dog! Just that me and a friend were talking about it after talking to the man who gave me Misty (my border collie) who said she could still breed at 7 - I thought the oldest was 5?\n",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Date" : "2010-07-28 18:20:33",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Timestamp" : "1280341233",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Link" : "http://answers.yahoo.com/question/?qid=20100728112033AAb4hTA",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Type" : "Answered",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "CategoryId" : 396546021,
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "CategoryName" : "Dogs",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "UserId" : "cP16Ctgxaa",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "UserNick" : "Kiko",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "UserPhotoURL" : "http://l.yimg.com/dg/users/1t1USxJpxAAEBQOGZjBMW0-5Wp_EG.medium.jpg",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "NumAnswers" : 8,
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "NumComments" : 0,
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "ChosenAnswer" : "You just \"imagined\" that ,dear...not \"thought\". & your imagination is WRONG.\r\n\r\n9 or even 10,for a healthy TOP-PRODUCING bitc-h.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n*&* bitches are SPAYED & dogs are CASTRATED......big scary correct ADULT words.",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "ChosenAnswererId" : "clN6YITvaa",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "ChosenAnswererNick" : "Debunker",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "ChosenAnswerTimestamp" : "1280317077",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "ChosenAnswerAwardTimestamp" : "1280835336"
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):        },      {
```

I parse through it and display it but when it returns this to my `json` string

```
    09-02 00:25:55.466: D/JSON String(882): {
    09-02 00:25:55.466: D/JSON String(882): "all" : {
    09-02 00:25:55.466: D/JSON String(882):     "count" : 0,
    09-02 00:25:55.466: D/JSON String(882):     "questions" : [     ]
    09-02 00:25:55.466: D/JSON String(882):     }
    09-02 00:25:55.466: D/JSON String(882): }
```

My code was suppose to display an error message and then return the user back to the main activity.  When it does return `count 0` my application doesn't do anything and what I mean by that is when the `doInBackground` method is complete it just shows a blank screen because the web service hasn't returned any data. it acts like the code I have been assisted with doesn't even exist.  So I was just hoping somebody could assist me with this and you guys can help figure out what is going on.

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                try {

                    if (Integer.parseInt(json.getJSONObject("all").getString("count"))<=0){return "0";

                    }else{

                    JSONArray questions = json.getJSONObject("all").getJSONArray("questions");

                    for(int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject question = questions.getJSONObject(i);


                    String Subject = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
                    String ChosenAnswer = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
                    String Content = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);



                               HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, Subject);
                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT, Content);
                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER, ChosenAnswer);

                               questionList.add(map);

                    }


                    }} catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                return TAG_QUESTION ;           

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_URL) {

            if(TAG_COUNT == null || TAG_COUNT.equals("0")){
                Toast.makeText(ListView.this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();

            }else{

            if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
                        R.layout.listelements,
                        new String[] { TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT }, new int[] {
                        R.id.Subject,});

                setListAdapter(adapter);                

            }}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never use the result of `doInBackground` in your `onPostExecute()` method, that's why nothing happens.

In your case, `doInBackground` return a `String`, and `onPostExecute()` accepts a `String` as parameter (`file_URL`).

In `doInBackground`, when it's okay, you return `TAG_QUESTION`, which must be a constant declared elsewhere in your code, and when it fails, you return `"0"`. 
So, in `onPostExecute()`, `file_URL` will contain either the value of `TAG_QUESTION` or `"0"`. The thing is that you never check its content. Moreover, in `doInBackground`, you never change the value of `TAG_COUNT`.

So if you want to check if `count` is null, you should replace the line

```
if(TAG_COUNT == null || TAG_COUNT.equals("0")){
```

by

```
if(file_URL.equals("0")) {
```

That should do it.

(Ideally it would be better to return an `int` instead of a `String` in `doInBackground` if you just want to know the number of items)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to automate the parsing of the document. You can create corresponding java classes for the json objects. The integer, string values can be mapped as is. Json can be parsed like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
Response r = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Response.class);
```

You have a full example in this **[link](http://androidsmith.com/2011/07/using-gson-to-parse-json-on-android/)**